# Show progress bar while loading web content in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP7 application I loade some simple text data from the web.

```
 string url = "home url";

 var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

 var result = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
```

And this is how I consume the data

```
private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
            {
                someLabelValue.Text = contents;
            });
    }
}
```

I added a indeterminate progress bar to my layout. Now I want to display it when my application is loading the data from the web.

How can I do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way, to see it working is to go and change the .Visiblility of the progress bar to Visible when you make the call (top code extract) and call .Visibility = Collapsed when it's done (in the second sample, inside your BeginInvoke() block).

Answer (score 1):

As Shahar says you will need to set the visible property of your progress bar to true when your call back starts and false when it ends. You could also need to modify your call back to obtain the progress you have made.

You can obtain the total amount of data to download from WebResponse.ContentLength property (response.ContentLength in your example). Then rather than calling ReadToEnd, you would read the stream in chunks so that you can update the amount downloaded before the download is complete.

NOTE: ContentLength only works if the server sends the Content-Length HTTP header. For performance reasons, some servers start sending their response before they have decided what the end of the response is going to be. In this instance they don't know how big the response will be when they send the HTTP header and thus can't set the ContentLength. In this instance ContentLength is set to -1 and you will not be able to calculate a persentage complete.

Finally if you are downloading a large file it might be better to use a BackgroundTransferRequest object instead as this will continue to work even when your application has been deactivated or tombstoned. This is only available in the Mango (7.1) release though.